# How to escape * in regex password pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

I use validate.js for form validation and have a password pattern where I would like to allow only one of the following special characters: -!@_#+

Password pattern is as below:

```
 password1: {
  pattern:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[-!@_#+])(?=.{8,})/
},
```

However, when I enter *, $ or % character as password input no error message is given.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: with a \ - but which `*` did you want to escape?

Comment: Why would you want to limit a user's password options?

Comment: Hello, I would like to exclude * from the following special characters list (?=.*[-!@_#+])

Comment: For our client's restrictions, cannot change it

Comment: Can you add your input and code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really limiting the input options of the user, your pattern says:
From the starting position of string, check if it is followed by a lower case letters, then check if it is followed by a uppercase letters, followed by numbers and then some symbols.

There is nothing to limit the users input. Since `.*` will match any char that is not a line terminator(\n, \r etc).

You should try something like this: `/^([-\w!@#+]+){8,}$/`
Here `\w` mathces a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore.

Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/TINm56/1

[image]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it still matches * , $, and % characters

Comment: @Nimet it doesnt, check this link: https://regex101.com/r/TINm56/2

Comment: Yes, thank you it works :) When seeing "1 match" text, I tought it's still matching -did not take into consideration other sample strings. Sorry and thank you

Comment: @Nimet add it between + and ], like this;`[-\w!@#+.]`